# Scaling number interval

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set of numbers $x_i$ that satisfies following inequality $a\leq x_i \leq b$.

I need to scale this set to set $y_i$ so that it will satisfy $c\leq y_i \leq d$, but their relative position must stay the same (so for example when I have set $X=\{-2,\ -1,\ 0,\ 1,\ 2\}$, then if $c=-4,\ d=4$, then $Y=\{-4,\ -2,\ 0,\ 2,\ 4\}$.

I need to derive a formula that could transform $x_i$ to $y_i$

(I need this for a program that interpolates functions using Chebyshew roots as nodes, I can calculate them for interval $[-1;1]$ and I need to scale them for any interval)

I know how to do it when $c<0<d$ - I just multiply negative numbers by $\frac{c}{a}$ and positive ones by $\frac{d}{b}$, but I don't know how to do it for any $a,\ b,\ c,\ d$

Comment: Don't you just want to find the equation of the line $y=Ax+B$ that passes through the two points $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$?

Comment: @saulspatz oh, you are right! Thank you!